# Python: Create dataframe with 'uneven' column entries

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe where the column lengths are not equal. How can I do this?
I was trying to use `groupby`. But I think this will not be the right way.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'filename':['file1','file1'], 'variables':['a','b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped = df.groupby('filename')
print(grouped.get_group('file1'))
```

Above is my sample code. The output of which is:

[image: Output of above code]

What can I do to just have one entry of `'file1'` under `'filename'`?
Eventually I need to write this to a csv file.

Thank you

Comment: The column lengths cannot be different. If you don't have a value in some rows you can replace them with `np.nan` values when building the dataframe. These wouldn't be written to .csv. A fuller answer to your question really requires knowing more about where the data is coming from, and what you intend to do with it when it's in a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one entry in a column the other will be NaN. So you could just filter the NaNs by doing something like `df = df.at[df["filename"].notnull()]`

Comment: My script is writing all the columns. So the columns show up like the way they do as in my question. They don't show up as NaN

Comment: im was talking about the rows in a column and not the column itself, if you only have 1 row with data in the filename column teh other row will be nan, and then you can filter

Comment: I am sorry I am not clear. My code outputs two variables - (Filename - only one) and (Variables - more than one)

Comment: I am sorry I am not clear. My code outputs two variables - (Filename - only one) and (Variables in that file- more than one). I need to stack these in two columns so that first column has only one cell with the filename. The second column has multiple the variables listed down. The For Loop then outputs another filename and associated variables which I have to stack below the first output. Hence first column will have less entries. Second column will have more entries. I was thinking of then converting it to a dataframe and using csvwrite.

Comment: Okay but you cannot have different column lengths in an dataframe, so either you skip the dataframe part of you just use it to write the data to a csv ( you can easily write data as csv with the built in csv library) or you have to fill your columns with the filenames. But you cannot have different column lengths